# I need to be able to get the Dropdown box Value to pass over to the onClick Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the color off table cell's when clicked using the colour that is selected on the Dropdown box, I am quite new to jQuery so I am kind of stuck.

At the moment in the table all off my Cell's have this code on them turning them red when they are clicked but i have a dropdown box at the bottom off the page that i want to change the color off the onclick color to the value off the dropdown box

I have put the code for the table, script and Dropdown List that i have used below.

```
 <table class="tg" id="nr" align="center">

    <tr>

}
    <th class="tc"</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">12</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="tc">Monday</th>
    <td class="tc-031e" id="mycell </td>>
     <td onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'myVar'; " class="tc-031e">
```

```
       </table>





<script>
 function color_change(){
var sel = document.getElementById('color'),
myVar = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("tg-031e").style.backgroundColor=myVar;
     </script>




<p style="width: 1016px; text-align: center;">
        &nbsp;Choose a Color&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="Color" id="Color">
<option value="#ff0000">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>

</p>
```

Comment: Your question title doesn't match its content. What's your question?

Comment: I need some Jquery that will change the value off the onclick color but im not sure how to do it.

Comment: @Lewis , u forgot to close <p> and <td> making it invalid HTML

Comment: I have tried a few things, but they didnt work im not so experienced in Jquery im trying to learn

Comment: then write here what did u try RECENTLY that didnt work . Else u will get downvotes here and Question wil get deleted,.

Comment: Ok, Sorry for wasting your time I have only just signed up here i will put what i tried in a comment now

Comment: @Lewis , no dont write in comment.Edit the Question and update Question with What u tried

Comment: @PratikJoshi Is that more clearer?

Comment: @Lewis ,yes now it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot easier if you use jQuery and the click event.

[Make sure you have included jQuery.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp)

**HTML:**

```
<table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>Choose a Color
    <select name="Color" id="Color">
        <option value="#ff0000">Red</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.tg td').click(function () {
        var theColor = jQuery('#Color').val();
        jQuery(this).css('background-color', theColor);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pa3uK/)

Comment: @JamieDunstant Thanks this is what i need, I am extremely new with jQuery how do i put the jQuery in the code i tried <script> jQuery('.tg td').click(function () {
    var theColor = jQuery('#Color').val();
    jQuery(this).css('background-color', theColor);
}); </script> but this didnt work

Comment: @Lewis - See my edits. Firstly, make sure you have included the jQuery library. There is a link in my post explaining how to do this. Also, attach the `click` event on document ready as in the example above.